# Using Google Material Design Lite tabs with href attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design-lite

I'm using Google's MDL tabs in navigation. But - instead of the tabs revealing content already in view, I want to simply put an `href` attribute and send user's the appropriate route (using `ngRoute`).

MDL's library throws this error (since it's trying to find that tab's content on the page):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '#/url1' is not a valid selector.

Is there any way around this? or a better way to accomplish this? I don't want to make a new class copying a tab's CSS, because then i'd have to synchronize it as MDL updates.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('controller', function($scope){
      $scope.urls = ['#/url1', '#/url2', '#/url3', '#/url4'];
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller" class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <a ng-repeat="url in urls" ng-href="{{url}}" class="mdl-layout__tab">{{url}}</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    asdf
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Why nobody answer this question after 1 year...?? this question is my problem too